# df command across multiple os

Tags: python, linux, solaris, expect

The df command displays the amount of disk space occupied by mounted or unmounted file systems, the amount of used and available space, and how much of the file system's total capacity has been used.

Linux has df command in the following location ***/bin*** whereas in Solaris in the following location ***/usr/gnu/bin***...

If suppose ***/usr/bin*** is set in the PATH, then programmatically, i need to ensure that one of required df (as mentioned above) is invoked instead of the user defined df.

**One solution** to this problem is using uname to get the OS and set the df accordingly... Is there any other better way to do this where i am not dependent on the OS.

Note: the default df and gnu df give different outputs hence i need to invoke the required df command on two different OS programmatically (the paths are mentioned above)

**DID NOT FIND ANY SOLUTION TO THE PROBLEM** 
Used the alternative solution that i had provided in the question itself!

Comment: I haven't used Solaris in a couple of decades, but I'm pretty sure df wasn't in /usr/local. That's for local additions to the OS, not for standard utilities.

Comment: @Barmar, you are right... corrected the paths... but the question remains the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution top this problem seems using uname to get the OS and
 set the df accordingly... same as what i had stated in the problem!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no "default" df on Solaris. You have various `df` commands, each one designed to suit specific needs.

- `/usr/bin/df` is the one used by default by root and most users in Solaris 10 and older installations. This is the one used by all system scripts.
- `/usr/xpg4/bin/df` is the POSIX compliant version used by people and scripts requiring standard compliance.
- `/usr/gnu/bin/df` is the GNU version of `df` only available with Solaris 11 and newer, it appears first in non root users default PATH, but not on root default PATH.

Of course, users are free to change their PATH to have a specific `df` to appears first, or even a customized one not described here, a function, an alias, whatever.

If you want to write a portable script that doesn't rely on user or system customizations, you can run this command:

```
PATH=$(getconf PATH) df
```

If you want to use a specific `df` version that has its own extensions like `GNU df`, you need to prepend the directory where this command is located to the PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

Are the target systems somehow under your control, and does this involve a limited set of servers?

If so, how about adding a soft link in both the Solaris and Linux servers, in the same location and with the same name?

Something like:

- Solaris: `ln -s /usr/gnu/bin/df /usr/bin/my_df`
- Linux: `ln -s /bin/df /usr/bin/my_df`

Then let your script use `/usr/bin/my_df` for every box.

Not fancy and rather simple approach... but maybe it would work for you?

Just my 2c.

Comment: Oh well... it was worth a shot. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you fire any command in any unix variant then it checks you PATH env variable. It check the command in each directory in the same sequence mentioned in PATH env variable.

So in you shell script just set PATH variable so that default df path will come at the beginning like below.

```
PATH = Defaut_df_path:$PATH
```

Whatever be the OS, if you fire "df" it will be your default "df".

System Admin Solution-
Please do this in .bashrc file ( or bash-profile) . Next time df will always trigger default df.

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
default_path='/usr/bin';
PATH=$default_path:$PATH;
echo $PATH;
df
which df  ## this will give you path which you are using
```

Programming solution-
If you are writing some shell script then please do this before using df. It will set for that particular run.

I think in most linux varient df default location is /bin or /usr/bin. So setting these path are suffice. Also you can check if /bin/df exists then run /bin/df otherwise /usr/bin/df like below.

```
if [ -e /bin/df ]
then
/bin/df
else
/usr/bin/df
fi
```

Comment: okay, in my case both the df paths are set... and gnu location comes before the df location... which is not what i want...

Comment: Maybe i didnt explain the question well... Since the PATH is different on different OS, i need a programmatic solution to avoid if... else conditions in the script to set the PATH... i dont want the user to modify his PATH...

Comment: @Nida- please use above script

Comment: okay this hardcoding for path will work for one OS... what about the other OS ?

Comment: I am sure that all default 'df' command location are /usr/bin or /bin only. So just hardcode this path. Can you please tell some exception or this rule.

Comment: Mentioned the paths for linux and solaris in the question itself

Comment: I am not using solaris currently. but in solaris it is in /usr/bin only as per man page and this si default df. http://www.bga.org/~lessem/psyc5112/usail/man/solaris/df.1.html

Comment: there is /usr/gnu/bin as well... and in linux in /bin folder, i need to use Df from the above locations without using uname or if conditions

Answer (score 0):

From what I could gather you have two variants of 'df' in the solaris system. My suggestion: modify the environment variables before you start the process. Doing that with python's subprocess interface is quite easy.

#### solution 1

Try calling `platform.uname()` and check if the os is solaris or linux. I think the call returns a tuple about the operating system.

```
import subprocess, os , platform
if(os.platform()[0] == 'Solaris') 
     my_env = os.environ.copy()
     my_env["PATH"] = "/usr/bin:" + my_env["PATH"]
     subprocess.Popen(my_command, env=my_env)

subprocess.Popen(my_command, env=NONE)
```

#### solution 2

Since the call checks each entry in PATH one by one, prepend [X]( the path of df you like) to PATH. If its solaris it gets picked up otherwise it moves on to the next entry in PATH.

Comment: what you have understood is one part of the problem, the second part is that two OS have different locations for the command, and the script needs to work for both

Comment: @NidaSahar, try to check if the system is solaris or linux and then modify the path for the process.

Comment: I have already mentioned that solution in the question itself... i was looking at an alternate method, that was the basic reason for posting the question